# Solving $8yy'^2 - 2xy' + y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving the differential equation $8yy'^2 - 2xy' + y = 0$

My attempt:

We divide both sides by $x$, obtaining:

$$8\frac{y}{x}y'^2 - 2y' + \frac{y}{x} = 0$$

Then, we introduce $t = y'$, hence the differential equation becomes:

$$8\frac{y}{x}t^2 - 2t + \frac{y}{x} = 0$$

from which follows:

$$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{2t}{8t^2 +1}$$

Hence, in parametric equation we obtain:

$$\begin{cases} y' = t \\ \frac{y}{x} = \frac{2t}{8t^2 +1}\end{cases}$$

From the second equation, after differentiating with respect to $t$, we obtain:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{2t}{8t^2 + 1} + \frac{-16t^2 + 2}{(8t^2 +1)^2}$$

Hence:

$$dy = dx\frac{2t}{8t^2 + 1} + \frac{-16t^2 + 2}{(8t^2 +1)^2}dt$$

From the first equation we have $dy = tdx$

Therefore:

$$tdx= dx\frac{2t}{8t^2 + 1} + \frac{-16t^2 + 2}{(8t^2 +1)^2}dt$$

Or after rearranging:

$$dx = \frac{-2dt}{(8t^2+1)dt}$$

And by integrating:

$$x(t) = -2\ln|t| - \frac{1}{2}\ln|8t^2 + 1| + c$$

And by the first equation:

$$y(t) = \frac{2t}{8t^2+1}(-2\ln|t| - \frac{1}{2}\ln|8t^2 + 1| + c)$$

Hence, the solution in parametric equation, is:

$$\begin{cases} x(t) = -2\ln|t| - \frac{1}{2}\ln|8t^2 + 1| + c \\ y(t) = \frac{2t}{8t^2+1}(-2\ln|t| - \frac{1}{2}\ln|8t^2 + 1| + c) \end{cases}$$

Can someone verify whether this is correct? The answer my book gives is $$y^2 - 4cx + 32c^2 = 0$$ with singular integral $$8y^2 - x^2 = 0$$ How would I derive this answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost the factor $x$ in the last term while differentiating the parametric equation.

---

It is even easier to multiply with $y$ and then substitute $u=y^2$ to get
$$
2u'^2-xu'+u=0\iff u=xu'-2u'^2
$$
which is a Clairaut differential equation. This has the lines
$$
u=cx-2c^2
$$
as solutions and their envelope which is the non-linear solution to $0=(x-4u')u''$. Thus inserting $u'=x/4$ gives
$$
u=\frac{x^2}4-\frac{x^2}8=\frac{x^2}8
$$

Comment: I keep making silly mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask how you saw that you could multiply with y and then make the substitution? Is it experience or is this something obvious?

Comment: Because of the leading term, first try to absorb the singularity. Most (non-linear) ODE that are suitable as a text book or tutorial exercise have such a simple trick to solve them, as even slight variations in the composition of terms can lead to non-solvable equations.