# Difficulty in integrating this differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonality

How to integrate the following differential equation?
$$y\cdot \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 + 2x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} -y = 0$$

Comment: it is not function,it is a differential-equation

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful to state what your thoughts and attempts on the problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @Anuj: **Hint:** Let $y = v x \implies y' = v + v' x'$, substitute those two items and then rearrange and solve.

Comment: This is a d'Alambert's equation. you can see step by step solution at wolfram alpha.

Comment: I tried y = vx but this would make the existing equation much more tedious as the middle terms in the equation is of the form (x/y)

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255914/solving-8yy2-2xy-y-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the equation with $y$ and set $u=y^2$. Then the ODE for $u$,
$$
u=xu'+\frac14u'^2
$$
is a [Clairaut DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut's_equation) with its family of linear solutions
$$
u=cx+\frac14c^2
$$
and the envelope of this family where
$$
\frac12u'+x=0\implies u=-x^2
$$
Obviously, there are some restrictions to taking the real-valued square root so that only partial functions of the linear family give solutions for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$y(y')^2+2x y'-y=0$$ solve for $y'$ to get two solution $$y'=\frac{\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{y}$$ Now, introduce $y=u x$ to get $$u+xu'=\frac{\pm\sqrt{u^2+1}-1}{u}$$ Solving for $x$, the equation becomes$$u+\frac x {x'}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{u^2+1}-1}{u}\implies \frac {x'}x=\frac{u}{\pm\sqrt{u^2+1}  -(u^2+1)}$$ which is separable leading to $$x=\frac{c_1}{1\pm\sqrt{u^2+1}}$$ Go back to $u$ and then to $y$.